# Why does the iTunes artist list jump to start when I scroll it?

Tags: itunes

I updated my iTunes yesterday, along with Lion, as did a lot of other people. Now I've been experiencing some weird behaviour.

[image]

I have my iTunes setup like above. I usually browse to artist by typing the first few letters of their name, and the list jumps down to the results. It still does that. However, when I scroll the list afterwards it jumps to the very top of the list, regardless of scroll direction.

Have anyone experience similar problems? And if so, how have you solved it?

Edit: Problem has been solved in the new iTunes 10.5.1

Comment: Just to let you know you're not the only one ;)
I have the same problem since my last iTunes update. It's really annoying. Do not how to solve it yet. More infos here : https://discussions.apple.com/message/16335291#16335291

Comment: Ah, figures. New versions of iTunes usually introduces some weird little bug.

Comment: same thing here. only started recently. selecting an item by clicking on it doesn't change the behavior of jumping to the top of the list when i do any scrolling.

Comment: The problem has been solved now with iTunes 10.5.1

Answer (score 1):

It's probably scrolling to where the cursor is, and since you searched, the cursor has been reset and moved to the top of the list.  Click once in the list to select a visible item, then scroll.

Comment: Nope, it does even when I do that!